# Iterating through a list of users and pushing to an array in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have this script that returns a list of all users. I would like to have:

- set the viewModel's totalUsers and page properties based on data returned.
- Iterate through the list of users and push the last user object into the observableArry
- push() method adds users to already loaded and shown users

**Purpose** 
I actually want to get a count of all users because i will be loading 20 users a page and when i reach the bottom of the page i will check if i still have more users to load and then load them. That way if i have 400 users - they won't be all loaded at once and take up time.

**Knockout JS File**

```
$.views.Roster.RosterViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.RosterUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    _rosterUsers = self.RosterUsers;
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
    self.toDisplay = ko.observable(20);
    self.filteredRoster = ko.computed(function(){
        var init = (self.currentPage()-1)* self.toDisplay(),
            filteredList = [],
            rosterLength = self.RosterUsers().length,
            displayLimit = self.toDisplay();
        if(rosterLength == 0)
            return[];
        for(var i = init; i<(displayLimit + init) - 1 && i<rosterLength; i++)
        {
            filteredList.push(self.RosterUsers()[i]);
        }
        return filteredList;
    }),
    totalRoster = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.RosterUsers().length;
    }),
    changePage = function (data) {
        currentPage(data);
    },
    next = function () {
        if ((self.currentPage() * self.toDisplay()) > self.RosterUsers().length)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() + 1);
    },
    prev = function () {
        if (self.currentPage() === 1)
            return;

        self.currentPage(self.currentPage() - 1);
    },

    $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.AddUsers(data);
};
```

**HTML View Page**

```
<script  type="text/html" id ="grid">

    <section id="rosterImages" style=" float:left">
    <section id="users">
        <div id="nameImage">
            <figure id="content">
                <img width="158" height="158" alt="Gravatar" data-bind="attr:{src: GravatarUrl}"/>
                <figcaption>
                    <a title="Email" id="emailIcon" class="icon-envelope icon-white" data-bind="attr:{'href':'mailto:' + Email()}"></a>
                    <a title="Profile" id="profileIcon" class="icon-user icon-white"></a>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <p data-bind="text:Name"></p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</script>

<ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: prev">Prev</a></li>
          <!-- ko foreach: ko.utils.range(1, totalRoster()/toDisplay() + 1) -->
          <li><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.changePage"></a></li>
          <!-- /ko -->
        <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: next">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**Update: Scroll Script**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            if (parseInt($.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.currentPage(), "10") * 20 < parseInt($.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.totalRoster(), "10")) {
                $.views.Roster.RosterViewModel.next();
            }
        }
    });
```

How can i make these additions with what i already have? Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Are you planning to page the data in the client side? What I mean is, are you planning to get all the users and set up a pager on the client side? Or is your server getting the data for which page you are on etc?

Comment: @sujeshArukil yes on the client side - this is the beginning process because i will be adding a scroll feature that will load the next batch of users as they scroll and there are still users in the array.

Comment: maybe I have never seen this. the option "limit" in your ajax request. What is it? I seriously cannot find any documentation on it.

Comment: @sujeshArukil i saw it in a tutorial done by someone: http://www.strathweb.com/2012/03/build-facebook-style-infinite-scroll-with-knockout-js-and-last-fm-api/

Comment: that looks right. The tutorial is passing it in the data object, not as a limit option to $.ajax it self. if you say the server is returning all records and does not care about the page and page size right? In which case, your ajax is returning all the data, you attach a computed to your model to get the count.

Comment: @sujeshArukil so from what i understand from you is that `limit` is not or won't be doing anything because i am not specifying a specific data to be passed in.

Comment: that is right. if you are getting all the data at once from the server, there is no need for a limit to be part of the request sent to the server, because the server doesn't care. Once you get the data, push it to your observableArray. Add a computed value to your viewmodel that returns the length of your observableArray (i.e. total records), add another computed that will return the paged values from the observableArray, this is what you will bind to.

Comment: @sujeshArukil is it possible to provide an example or prototype code?

Comment: sure. Working on it. give me 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEre you go. I have mimicked the getRoster ajax call for the fiddle. in your case, you will be making a "GET" call and not a "POST".

http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/z8vpx/4/

rosterArray is the main observableArray that will store the entire list from the server, filteredRoster will get the data from the rosterArray based on the currentPage, toDisplay stores the limit, currentPage tracks the current page, totalRoster is computed that returns the total elements in the array

```
var rosterArray = ko.observableArray(),
    currentPage = ko.observable(1),
    toDisplay = ko.observable(20),
    filteredRoster = ko.computed(function(){
        var init = (currentPage() - 1) * toDisplay(),
            filteredList = [],
            rosterLength = rosterArray().length,
            displayLimit = toDisplay();

        if(rosterLength === 0)
            return [];

        for(var i = init; i < (displayLimit + init) - 1 && i < rosterLength; i++){
            filteredList.push(rosterArray()[i]);
        }

        return filteredList;
    }),
    totalRoster = ko.computed(function(){
        return rosterArray().length;
    }),
    changePage = function(data){
        currentPage(data);
    },
    next = function(){
        if((currentPage() * toDisplay()) > rosterArray().length)
            return;

        currentPage(currentPage() + 1);
    },
    prev = function(){
        if(currentPage() === 1)
            return;

        currentPage(currentPage() - 1);
    };
```

Hope that helps.

-Suj

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in helping me but i just want to get a few things cleared up. Excuse my lack of knowledge on this - this is my first experience with knockout. So i just copied your code and i placed it in my knockoutjs file (my original posted code) and i copied your html from jsfiddle into my html so i can get an idea but  with the added html i am only getting one user to show on page with `prev` and `next` buttons and the numbering within is empty. I will update my original post.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: go to the dev tools and tell me what errors you see in the console. and did you replace the entire code you had with the code from the fiddle? Did you remove the ajax call that I am making?

Comment: there is: `Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: prev is not defined;
Bindings value: click: prev ` i didn't replace the entire html because my view is placed in a template because i have a toggle button that toggles between two templates - this one(grid view) and a list view

Comment: for your code above - is it supposed to be in a specific place in the js file that i have? I think i am integrating your code into mine in a wrong way

Comment: take each of my variable declarations and add it to the "this" object in your RosterViewModel. Yes, you are integrating it wrong.

Comment: I really appreciate your help - you were the only one for days i've been stuck on this. So i moved and updated my code above the RosterViewModel and the HTML but currently i am only getting 10 users on the page and the pagination shows only 1 page. if i hard code to load 40 users on the page - the 40 are loaded and pagination shows 3 pages but when i click on them nothing changes because all the users are loaded on page 1.

Comment: Thank you thank you - i got it working with the pagination next and prev but not clicking on the actual number. But i am actually going to use the scroll feature to load as i scroll. Same as the tutorial i had you look at earlier. I updated what i think the script should be for the scroll but can you take a look at it? You have been an amazing help!

Comment: Your code for scrolling looks right. The reason cgangePage is not working is bciz you are not referencing currentPage right. Change it to self.currentPage in the change function. Happy that you got it working. Good luck.

Comment: after giving it some thought. It doesn't seem that beneficial to have the pagination if i already know how many total users will return (i could load them all at once). But if i have 250 users i don't want to count all 250 into an array but load 20 on a page and every time i scroll 20 more will be loaded.  so i will need to alter the `for` loop correct?