# knockoutjs datasource example not working in jsfiddle

Tags: knockout.js, datasource

I would like to ask a question about the usage of datasource within knockout.
For that I tried to base my example on a jsfiddle but I can't even get this simple example to work.

This is the html code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: sales"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>            
</table>

<span id="pager">
    <button data-bind="click: items.pager.first">First</button>
    <button data-bind="click: items.pager.previous">Prev</button>
    <span class="summary">Page 
        <span data-bind="text: items.pager.page"></span> of 
        <span data-bind="text: items.pager.totalPages"></span></span>
    <button data-bind="click: items.pager.next">Next</button>
    <button data-bind="click: items.pager.last">Last</button>
</span>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
var initialData = [
  { id:1, name: "Well-Travelled Kitten", sales: 352, price: 75.95 },
  { id:2, name: "Speedy Coyote", sales: 89, price: 190.00 },
  { id:3, name: "Furious Lizard", sales: 152, price: 25.00 },
  { id:4, name: "Indifferent Monkey", sales: 1, price: 99.95 },
  { id:5, name: "Brooding Dragon", sales: 0, price: 6350 },
  { id:6, name: "Ingenious Tadpole", sales: 39450, price: 0.35 },
  { id:7, name: "Optimistic Snail", sales: 420, price: 1.50 }
];
function getAnimals() {
    var params = {
        limit: this.pager.limit(),
        startIndex: this.pager.limit() * (this.pager.page() - 1)
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: {
            json: ko.toJSON(initialData.slice(params.startIndex, params.startIndex + params.limit))
        },
        context: this,
        success: function(data) {
            this(data);
            this.pager.totalCount(7);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
};

var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([]).extend({
        datasource: getAnimals,
        pager: {
            limit: 3
        }
    })
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I always get the following javascript error:

Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: items.pager is undefined;
Bindings value: click: items.pager.first

**I just tested again and in Chrome it works fine, but in Firefox 20.0 under Ubuntu 12.10 it does not work!**

Any idea what could be wrong here: http://jsfiddle.net/sturm/pr9Sf/1/

Comment: You still having trouble with this? The paging in the fiddle you provided seems to work fine

Comment: I can't see any problem or error in your fiddle on chrome, is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: if it might help, I had provided a solution for paging here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973337/iterating-through-a-list-of-users-and-pushing-to-an-array-in-knockout/15975378#15975378 and the fiddle for the same is here http://jsfiddle.net/sujesharukil/z8vpx/4/. May not solve your particular issue, but if you need ideas for putting up a pager, then this might help/

Comment: Ok I now forked the fiddle I posted and updated knockout, but it still does not work in Firefox on Ubuntu :-( http://jsfiddle.net/sturm/pr9Sf/1/